# Converting csv file with Postcode data into shapefile in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, csv

I have Postcode data in a csv file that I need to convert to a shapefile in ArcGIS. I have already imported the csv as a table into ArcMap but I cannot seem to be able to convert into a shapefile.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What kind of data is that postcode data? Any coordinates or something else? Which country?

Comment: Its population data for UK using Postcodes as geographic reference. There is no coordinates

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: code-point opendata https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/code-point-open.html and it will be GB coverage not UK. code-point (polygons) is licenced https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/code-point-with-polygons.html

Answer (score 1):

You need some sort of geometry to create a sensible shapefile. On this shapefile you can join your data using the postcodes as the join-column. Some fast search brought up two possible sources. Otherwise you need to find some geodata that suits you.

https://www.freemaptools.com/download-uk-postcode-lat-lng.htm

http://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/

Comment: Thank you Matte, I managed to do it the long route way. I hosted the layer in ArcGIS online as it was a big file. I then exported it to ArcGIS Desktop and georeferenced to create a shapefile. It worked